# Tweepy Client.like() throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partition'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

Regarding the [tweepy docs](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#likes) for using Twitter API v2 i should be able to like a tweet with the following code.

```
import tweepy
from keys import keys

# bearer token for twitter developers
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=keys["bearer_token"])

# checks for latest tweets
def like_tweets():

    like = client.like(1466906017120153601)
    print(like)

like_tweets()
```

I both tried to pass the tweet id as a string and as an integer. I checked the tweet id manually for correctness and also tried different tweet ids.
But i get the following error everytime:

```
File "C:\Users\myname\pathtopython\Python\Python37\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 387, in like
id = self.access_token.partition('-')[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partition'
```

Do you have ideas or suggestions how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to encode the exact error, but found out, that this method need's the whole access data, including the `consumer_token, consumer_secret, access_token and access_token_secret`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the same issue.
The solution was to specify the other tokens when creating the client:

```
from os import environ
import tweepy

def new_client():
    return tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=environ['CONSUMER_KEY'],
    consumer_secret=environ['CONSUMER_SECRET'],
    bearer_token=environ['BEARER_TOKEN'],
    access_token=environ['ACCESS_TOKEN'],
    access_token_secret=environ['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET'],
)

client = new_client()
```

And then calling

```
client.like(tweet_id=tweet_id)
```

(letting the default option *user_auth=True*)